# At least some columns satisfy a condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of 50000+ rows and 1600+ columns. The first two columns of the data frame are factors and the remaining columns are numeric. I want to discard all rows that have cell values less than 0.1 (<0.1) in less than 80 columns for each row.

More specifically each row is a gene and the columns are samples. The values contain the expression of the gene in a specific sample. If the gene expression value is less than 0.1 in 80(5% of 1600) samples or less then I discard it.

I use the following code

```
df = df[rowSums(df>0.1)>=80, ]
```

`df>0.1` gives `True` or `False` for each element and I compute the `sum [True=1 and False = 0]` and if the sum is less than 80 , then the row is discarded.

However, since the first two columns of my data frame are factors, it doesnt seem to work that well. It would be of great help if I can choose rowSums only for certain columns. Another equivalent code was

```
df = df[apply(df[,-1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) sum(x>0.1)>=80}),]
```

Both don't work when I have factors in first two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
dfSubset <-
  df[rowSums(df[, -c(1:2) ] > 0.1) >= (ncol(df) - 2) * 0.05, ]
```

For rowsums we are excluding first 2 columns, and getting 5% of number of leftover columns (instead of using hard coded number 80).